# Where can I find math intense apps in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math

I have found many rails apps mainly on the enterprise, social networking kind of web apps. I see that Ruby is compared with some of the great OOPS languages like Java & C# but I am really finding it hard to get some **Math Intense apps**. Any knowledgeble input (links to sample programs etc.), where the usage of the language is shown with ease and is like jumpstart or show how the language can be used for variety of math probs, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ruby is terribly slow with math intense apps and not even close to Java/C* in this area. Just wrong choice.

Comment: Unless you go for rapid prototyping. Also: Rails is a framework for web MVC applications, so I wouldn't expect math apps in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, Ruby hasn't ventured very far into mathematical and scientific computing. Currently, there is a pre-alpha library called [SciRuby](http://sciruby.com/) that is attempting to bring more math oriented capabilities to Ruby. They are trying to build a NumPy/SciPy equivalent. A few projects that are under SciRuby with example usage are:

- [NMatrix](http://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix)
- [Rubyvis](http://rubyvis.rubyforge.org/)
- [Statsample](http://ruby-statsample.rubyforge.org/)

Each project has various examples on how to get started/contribute. A good place to start is  their docs and their mailing list.

Hope that helps.